# Python PostgreSQL WHERE condition with datetime

Tags: python, postgresql, where-clause

I have a postgres table with a column called "ts" which contains a Timestamp

Now i want so select the row from table where timestemp is equal to specific Timestamp, so i decided to write the following SQL statement in my python code

```
date_to_choose = '2020-04-22 06:34:08+00:00'

cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM data 
            ORDER BY ts DESC 
            WHERE ts = TO_TIMESTAMP('{0}','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS+00:00')""".format(date_to_choose))
```

this results in following error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SyntaxError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-85-ed294a40a103> in <module>
      9 cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM data 
     10             ORDER BY ts DESC
---> 11             WHERE ts = TO_TIMESTAMP('{0}','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS+00:00')""".format(date_to_choose))
     12 
     13 

SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "WHERE"
LINE 3:             WHERE ts = TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-04-22 06:34:08+00:...
                    ^
```

is there any help?

Comment: `order by` must be after `where` clause

Comment: Don't use `.format()` on SQL queries. Give the parameters to `.execute()` as documented.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally try to add the `WHERE` clause before the `ORDER BY` one. Please try it, and comment if it works.

Comment: i tried too and got following error message ```InFailedSqlTransaction: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block```

Comment: Try to pass the `format()` method, outside the `cur.execute`.

Comment: unfortunately does not work either, same error message

Comment: @janwe: the error is related to a previous problem that caused the transaction to abort. Use a `con.commit()` or `con.rollback()` before the `cur.execute(...)`.

Comment: ah that looks better, now i got

`InvalidDatetimeFormat: invalid value "{0}" for "YYYY"
DETAIL:  Value must be an integer.`

it looks like the returned date has following format

datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 22, 6, 34, 8, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=0, name=None)

Comment: so I thought I swapped `TO_DATE` for `TO_TIMESTAMP` but this results in same error